# Airflow set dag run note

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-api

How to use the note present in DAG runs panel from the ui?
I would want to programmatically fill it. For example changing the content depending the on the params passed to the DAG run
[image]

Comment: looks like you can do with API.   https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/set_dag_run_note

i don't know how to do with API though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After setting the bounty,I've figured out the solution:

In python, it can be done:

```
def update_dag_run_note(run_id):
    session = settings.Session()
    editable_dag_run = session.query(DagRun).filter(DagRun.run_id == run_id).one()
    editable_dag_run.note = "your note"
    session.add(editable_dag_run)
    session.commit()
```

or via API, It can be done as @Emma suggested in comments:

`Patch /api/v1/dags/{dag_id}/dagRuns/{dag_run_id}/setNote`
[stable-rest-api-ref](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/set_dag_run_note)